# Delay when typing in JetBrains PyCharm Terminal

Tags: terminal, pycharm, ide, delay, jetbrains-ide

Whenever I type in the PyCharm Terminal window there is a 0.5 sec or so delay. The effect is a sort of lag and is frustrating when typing. This does not occur anywhere else across my system.

Does anybody have an explanation/solution for this issue?